# Convert row data into column data using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I would like to convert row data into columns, where the column names are not from the data. I think that using Pivot will not give me the correct solution. Please see Image of what my data looks like and how I want it to look.

[image]

The number of rows returned in the example will continue to grow over time.

**My solution** :
Based on @Triv answered, I have managed to solve the problem using the rank function to create a new column and then using dynamic pivot SQL to transform the data.

Comment: I think you need a dynamic sql query.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm quite new to sql and don't know how to do this. Please can you share the sql to do this?

Comment: your sql-server's version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dynamic sql + [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE #SampleData
(
   AccountNumber int,
   Product varchar(20),
   ProductEndDate datetime
)

INSERT INTO #SampleData VALUES (1,'Fixed 10','2016-01-01'),(1,'Fixed 11','2016-02-01'),(1,'Fixed 13','2016-03-01'),(1,'Fixed 12','2016-04-01'),
                        (2,'Fixed 10','2016-01-01'),(2,'Fixed 11','2016-02-01'),(2,'Fixed 13','2016-03-01')

DECLARE @HeaderAll nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @ColumnPivotProduct nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @ColumnPivotProductEndDate nvarchar(max)

;WITH temp AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT 
   CONCAT('Product' ,row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY sd.AccountNumber ORDER BY sd.Product)) AS ProductGroup,
   CONCAT('ProductEndDate' ,row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY sd.AccountNumber ORDER BY sd.Product)) AS ProductEndDateGroup
   FROM #SampleData sd
)
SELECT @HeaderAll = STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',',t.ProductGroup,'= MAX(',t.ProductGroup, '),', t.ProductEndDateGroup ,'= MAX(', t.ProductEndDateGroup,')') FROM temp t FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1,''),
     @ColumnPivotProduct =  STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',',t.ProductGroup) FROM temp t FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1,''),
     @ColumnPivotProductEndDate =  STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',', t.ProductEndDateGroup) FROM temp t FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1,'')

--SELECT @HeaderAll, @ColumnPivotProduct, @ColumnPivotProductEndDate


DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = CONCAT(
      ';WITH temp AS
         (
            SELECT *, 
            CONCAT(''Product'' ,row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY sd.AccountNumber ORDER BY sd.Product)) AS ProductGroup,
            CONCAT(''ProductEndDate'' ,row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY sd.AccountNumber ORDER BY sd.Product)) AS ProductEndDateGroup
            FROM #SampleData sd
         )
      SELECT AccountNumber, ',@HeaderAll,' FROM           
          (
            SELECT t.AccountNumber, t.Product, t.ProductEndDate, t.ProductGroup,t.ProductEndDateGroup FROM temp t
          ) src
          PIVOT
          (
            MIN(Product) FOR ProductGroup IN (',@ColumnPivotProduct,')    
          ) pvt
          PIVOT
          (
            MIN(ProductEndDate) FOR ProductEndDateGroup IN (',@ColumnPivotProductEndDate,')    
          ) pvt1
      GROUP BY AccountNumber           
       ')

PRINT @query
exec(@query)


DROP TABLE #SampleData
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/AEQBZ56634

Note: `CONCAT` is avaiable in sql-server 2012+. IF you are using an older version, then use `+` for concatenating string

Answer (score 0):

It works, check this out, Instead of @testTable  use your table name

```
 declare @temptable varchar(1000) = 'declare @tempTable1 table (',

@inserStatement varchar(1000) = 'insert into @tempTable1 (',

@insertValues varchar(1000) = ''

DECLARE @AcountNumber VARCHAR(50),@Product varchar(40),@ProductEndData varchar(50), @increment int = 0;

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
select 
Product,
ProductEndData from @testTable  

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Product, @ProductEndData 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
set @increment = @increment+1;
       SET @temptable += 'Product'+ cast(@increment as varchar) +' varchar(100),' + 'Product' + cast(@increment as varchar) + 'EndDate varchar(100),' ;
        set @inserStatement += 'Product'+ cast(@increment as varchar) +',' + 'Product' + cast(@increment as varchar) + 'EndDate,';

      set @insertValues += '(''' + @Product +''''+ ',' + ''''+ @ProductEndData + '''' + ')';


       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO  @Product, @ProductEndData   

END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

set @temptable = STUFF(@temptable, LEN(@temptable), 1, ')')
set  @inserStatement = STUFF(@inserStatement, LEN(@inserStatement), 1, ')')
set @insertValues = replace(@insertValues, ')(', ',')
exec (@temptable + @inserStatement + ' values ' +  @insertValues + 'select * from @tempTable1')
```